# Joomla - less :extend in Gantry framework

Tags: joomla, less, extend

I cannot properly `:extend` a class in Gantry framework.
I'm trying to do:

```
.mybox:extend(.box3) {
   /* Customization */
}
```

but it's not working.
I'm wondering whether it could be a version-related `less` compiler issue.

I tried defining `mybox` in `template-custom.less` and `header-light-custom.less` (because `.box3` is in `header-light.less` and I'm using the "light" header), with no luck.

Comment: Doesn't Gantry use lessphp? If so you can't use `extend` there since lessphp does not support this feature.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know that, thanks. If you write it as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gantry's PHP compiler doesn't support extends. It's planned to include support for extends in lessphp 1.4, https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/issues/426, though whether Rockettheme will update their implementation at that time is another matter.

You could simply disable Gantry's compiler and use your own, which is my preference;

http://internet-inspired.com/wrote/tutorials/disabling-gantrys-less-compiler/